# Issue with Rendering Image Swatch Colors on Product Page

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am currently working on a project where I need to implement image swatches on a product page. However, I seem to be facing an issue with the code

I have used the following code for the image swatches, but it does not seem to be working as expected

```js
class ColorName extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.color = this.parentNode.innerText;
        this.optionSelects = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        this.optionSelects.addEventListener(
            "change",
            this.colorRender.bind(this)
        );
        THIS.colorRender();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.color);
        console.log(this.optionSelects);
    }

    colorRender() {
        this.selectedColor = document.querySelector(
            `input[name="Color"]:checked`
        ).value;
        this.innerText =
            this.selectedColor.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            this.selectedColor.slice(1);
    }
}

customElements.define("color-name", ColorName);

class SizeName extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.size = this.parentNode.innerText;
        this.optionSelects = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        this.optionSelects.addEventListener(
            "change",
            this.sizeRender.bind(this)
        );
        THIS.sizeRender();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.size);
        console.log(this.optionSelects);
    }

    sizeRender() {
        this.selectedSize = document.querySelector(
            `input[name="Size"]:checked`
        ).value;
        this.innerText = this.selectedSize.toUpperCase();
        this.innerText =
            this.selectedSize.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            this.selectedColor.slice(1);
    }
}
```

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong here. I have tried reaching out to the original developer for assistance, but have not received a response yet.

Comment: can you please share the error message, which is showing on console